# Is there a way to show cards with a scroll bar option when the text data to be displayed is more in BOT developed through V4 in C#?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot

Query 1:
Is there a way to show cards with a scroll bar option when the text data to be displayed is more in BOT developed through V4 in C#?

in other words, the scroll bar should appear in a HERO card for example dynamically let take 2 examples:

Example 1: I have two lines to be displayed in the HERO card since the text is small the card will display these two lines with no issues.
Expected Result: The text should be displayed in a  HERO card without any scroll bar
Actual Result: Text displayed without scroll bar in a card

Example 2: I have more than lets say 30 lines of text to be displayed in a card
Expected Result: I want the text to be displayed inside a HERO card with scrollbar this scroll bar should appear based on text length as this time it is more rather than displaying the elongated card to display text i want the card size to be minimal with scroll bar enabled so that i can use scroll bar to read the text.
Actual Result: Not able to achieve this it displays an elongated card with all the required text

Issue: How to achieve the example 2 ask, is it possible to it in web channel chatbot? IF yes how to do it. Please provide a detailed step by step guide as I am new to BOT and code

Query 2:
Apart from this how to display a link to be displayed as a hyperlink inside a card instead of button click going to that URL I want a hyperlink to be displayed. For example, I have QnA Maker where I am getting answer displayed on a card where the answer contains a URL I want this URL to be displayed as a Hyperlink rather than normal text.

Currently, I am getting this as displayed as a text only, if I put the `href` tag in the QnA answer itself it is displaying this as a text with all the HTML tags.

ISSUE: How to display a URL as a hyperlink when displayed inside a HERO card?
is it possible to it in web channel chatbot? IF yes how to do it. Please provide a detailed step by step guide as I am new to BOT and code

Language: C#
SDK: V4
Channel: Web Channel Chat Bot

Thanks in Advance
-ChaitanyaNG

Tried to put some HTML tags inside QnA KB article but the output is coming from QnA as a raw text to be displayed meaning with all the HTML tags and if I display it as is in the web chat channel it is displaying with HTML tags.

It is provided in the query itself with my query explained with an example.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Adaptive Card for Multiple line with scroll bar property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-rich-cards?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

for Adaptive card direct link :- https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/

Here you will get how to design adaptive card with examples.

2. For show URL you need to get result from QNA Maker dialog and use ***String builder*** on that result.

if you are using web chat as channel then **href tag** will work. in bot emulator by default it will take as URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have two lines of text in hero cards. If you require more text you have to use adaptive cards.  Also adaptive cards can be customised to a wide range.
You can refer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#types-of-rich-cards